# Populate Listview in Excel Using Results In 2 Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, listviewitem

I need some guidance as this is something that has been bothering me for a while and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere...

I have a listviewbox on a userform which is populated by condition - searching through columns B and C to find the required strings. This is working fine.

However I need to extend the search to a second range of data which will look for the same strings but this time in columns AB and AC. I need both sets of results to populate the listbox.

Is this possible, and if so how?
Any help would be appreciated

The code I am using for the first population is below. I thought it would be simple to adjust and include the next range but apparently not

```
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim LstItem As ListItem
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim league As String
    
'Set the source
league = Worksheets("Stats").Range("BB1").Value
Set wksSource = Worksheets(league)
Set rngData = wksSource.Range("AA2").CurrentRegion

'Add the column headers
homelistView.ColumnHeaders.Clear
With Me.homelistView.ColumnHeaders
    .Add Width:=60
    .Add Width:=163, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=163, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=20, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=20, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=2, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=20, Alignment:=2
    .Add Width:=20, Alignment:=2
End With

'Count the number of rows in the source range
RowCount = rngData.Rows.Count

'Fill the ListView
Dim x As String
Dim p As String

x = Worksheets("Stats").Range("BD1").Value
p = Worksheets("Stats").Range("BD2").Value

For i = 2 To RowCount
    If (wksSource.Cells(i, "AB") = x And wksSource.Cells(i, "AC") = p) Or (wksSource.Cells(i, "AC") = x And wksSource.Cells(i, "AB") = p) Then
        Set item = homelistView.ListItems.Add(Text:=Format(wksSource.Cells(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy"))
        item.SubItems(1) = wksSource.Cells(i, 2)
        item.SubItems(2) = wksSource.Cells(i, 3)
        item.SubItems(3) = wksSource.Cells(i, 4)
        item.SubItems(4) = wksSource.Cells(i, 5)
        item.SubItems(5) = wksSource.Cells(i, 6)
        item.SubItems(6) = wksSource.Cells(i, 7)
        item.SubItems(7) = wksSource.Cells(i, 8)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Can you strip down your question to be more precise? There's clearly stuff in your code that isn't related to your question such as setting headers and it's unclear (to me) what's working (`b` and `c`?) and what isn't. Are you able to capture all of your correct values matching intersections or are you having trouble getting your matched results  and then having trouble putting them into the list?

Comment: So you're still using columns B-H to populate your listbox? Or should those shift over as well?

Comment: Also, what is `item`? Is that supposed to be `LstItem`? Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - After sat staring at the screen for ages I had a brainwave and solved it. The problem was in "wksSource.Cells(i, 2)", where I realised 2 is the column so by changing that to the "AB" etc I could retrieve the results I wanted